# Will all numbers be 100% unique in a table if to use this simple algorithm?

Tags: mysql, sql, uniqueidentifier

My goal is to insert a new and unique(unique is very important) number into a MySQL table on the server every time upon an event on a user's machine, using ajax.

So, server's part on user's event is doing this (using php):

- Finds a maximum value from the column in the db,
- Adds 10 to a maximum value,
- this is a new and unique (bigger than a maximum) value, we insert insert into a table.

Will all numbers be unique and go like 1, 11, 21, 31, if it starts from 1? I'm curious if inserting into the Table finishes before it starts performing another queue and coule be like 1, 11, 21, 21, 31, 41?

If it theoretically works like this (ordered by time)

1. find max  value from the column for the first user
2. find max a value from the column for the second user (it will be the same)
3. insert a (max+10) for the first user into the same table
4. insert a (max+10) for the second user into the same table (it will be the same), then the results will be the same, and 1 value could be repeated twice or even more...

So, the question is: will all numbers be 100% unique?
Depending on this I have to choose which algorithm to use for creating unique numbers.

Added:
Is it possible to be sure with this algorythm and without using autoincrements? Autoincrement is used for another column. Holes between numbers are OK. The only requirement is that numbers should be different, but with some "delta" that is more than one. Sorry I didn't notice about that in my question. Thank you.

Comment: Why not just use an auto-increment key?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth You can only have one auto incrementing column per table.

Comment: Either you're not aware of the column datatype that does this for you, or there are requirements you aren't telling us.

Comment: @Alex: max+1 would cause problems if two inserts happened at the exact same time.  Depending on the unique constraints, either one of the queries would fail or both rows would get the same value.

Comment: @Alex: Because guids are ugly and cumbersome.  '151543' is much less imposing than '1513512-2842-2344-1616-34c5643610fe' or whatever.  Particularly when the DB can auto-increment an int id for you, but you need to call a function to get a new guid.  It's better to avoid them if they're not absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a very specific reason against it, I recommend using [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) - it will scale much better and actually leave fewer "holes" in the sequence of numbers than your approach.

And you are correct - your approach will not actually guarantee uniqueness in concurrent environment. One way to make your algorithm work is to have a UNIQUE constraint on your field (if it is not already PRIMARY KEY) and then repeatedly attempt to insert a new value - if it fails just generate a new value and try again and it will eventually succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Use an auto incrementing column in the db

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use [autoincrement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using auto-increment on a separate column, you can still emulate it with something like the following.

```
insert into mytable (
  column1,
  column2,
  fake_auto_incr
) select
    'value for column1',
    'value for column2',
    max (fake_auto_incr) + 1
  from mytable
```

Because the `insert` is a transactional statement, ACID databases will ensure the `max+1` trick is always one greater then the current top value.

Keep in mind you'll need a slight adjustment for that to work on an empty table, since the query will return NULL in that case. This should suffice:

```
insert into mytable (
  column1,
  column2,
  fake_auto_incr
) select
    'value for column1',
    'value for column2',
    coalesce (max (fake_auto_incr), 0) + 1
  from mytable
```

This forces the initial value to 1 on an empty table, otherwise it uses the next available value.